# Check if plist file does not exist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsfilemanager

I know how to check if a plist file does exist...

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
 //..etc
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a plist file does not exist?

I am having some issues trying to use something from my plist when it's not present, as I create the plist later. So I would like to check if the plist is not present in the directory. I will pass some default values to the objects I am going to use.  That way I will not get an error; the if statement where I am comparing these values will not throw a fit, and later will get populated with the correct data.

Comment: AFAIK, `if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {}` checks if it does NOT exist. `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {}`checks if it DOES exist.

Comment: No offense, but if you can't solve that problem on your own, maybe you should be doing more basic things until you learn more.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I'm learning man, this was a confusing one as from my extensive testing `(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {}` is checking if file dose exist and `([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])` checks to see if file doesn't exists. I know this because I have deleted my plist file from my bundle and then added breakpoints at both if statments.. when the file dose not exists it enters `([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])` when it exists it enters `(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])`

Comment: I felt a need to ask the question because sometimes there are several different ways of solving problems where some are better than others. I thought maybe this was one of those situations where a different method call was happening ie "fileDoseNotExists". I searched for this but couldn't find it so to doubly make sure I decided to ask. don't get me wrong here I'm not mad at what you said it just upset me abit, as I'm trying my best and the reason I ask questions is because I want to learn.. I'm sure I could hack my way though 60% of the code,  but then I wouldnt be learning anything.

Comment: @AliHamze I just read this **The ! symbol here (and in front of any expression whose type is a pointer) returns a true (1)** I guess this is what is happening here as it backs up the testing I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code shown checks that the file does exist, you remove the `!` to check that it doesn't:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
```

Or, you can use:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] != 0) {
```

since the code returns 0 when the file does exist.  You might want to check `errno` or an equivalent to see if it is a permissions problems versus a non-existent file or directory.

Comment: oh man.. the thing with the ! I was reading it as not or not equal.. it was confusing the bajzzers out of me.. this worked thanks I will mark your answer correct shortly

Comment: Doesn't `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]` return true if the file DOES exist? So `![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]` should be checking if it does NOT exist. it's either that, or I need sleep...

Comment: honestly I have no idea anymore.. all I know is that `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]` succeeds when there is no dile and `![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]` succeeds when there is a file...